# PHP is single-threaded , How job and queue works in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I had an interview yesterday, He asked me a question. PHP is a single-threaded language then how jobs and queues work in laravel behind the scenes?

Comment: While this question is really vague (at least the way you put it here), I *think* what the interviewer wanted to hear is that there's one or more queue workers running as separate **processes** so there are no threads involved. Each process is independent and does not share any PHP memory with other processes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Single-threaded doesn't mean you can't launch multiple instances of the program, it means the program cannot execute multiple parts of itself simultaneously.

With this consideration in mind, you'll easily understand that when you are running the queue with `php artisan queue:work`, a new worker (a PHP process) starts and executes every new jobs pushed to the queue.

This worker runs alongside any other programs, single-threaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel queues are run as independently with PHP CLI using `php artisan queue:work` and has no relation with threading ...